# Ideal procedure to deal with faulty data for generation of LiDAR trajectory

Tags: lidr, point-cloud, trajectory

The reason for this post is to understand possible remedial measures when one is dealing with a lidar dataset that is faulty (incorrectly populated, missing trajectory information etc.). Obviously, re-acquisition is out of the question. Also, sometimes it is not possible to go back to the lidar operator.

Following steps(in `lidR` were attempted with an aim to understand the (problems with) data better:

**1) Using `track_sensor` without any knowledge about potential problems with the data**

`track_sensor` returned the following error

```r
las <- readLAS(lasfile)
traj <- track_sensor(las , Roussel2020())
#> Error: After keeping only first and last returns of multiple returns pulses, 6 pulses still have more than 2 points. This dataset is corrupted and gpstime is likely to be invalid.
```

**2) Dropping the problematic pulses that have more than two first and last returns**

The first and last returns are sufficient to define the vector representing the lidar pulse. Hence, the erroneous pulses (6 of them for this example) were dropped (for now). Also, single returns are also dropped as they cannot be used to define the pulse vector. We are left with a point cloud that has fewer points than the original.

```r
las <- readLAS(lasfile)

#filter duplicates
las <- filter_duplicates(las)

#drop intermediate returns as they are not necessary
las1 <- filter_firstlast(las)

#check if all pulses have only two returns i.e. first and last
#each gps time should have only two (first and last) returns 
las1@data[, nos := .N , by = c("gpstime")]

#keep only those points which are the first and last returns 
las1 <- filter_poi(las1, nos==2)

#generate trajectory
traj <- track_sensor(las1, Roussel2020())
#no error

#retain all the intermediate returns for the 'good' gpstimes 
las2 <- filter_poi(las, gpstime %in% las1@data$gpstime)
 
#no of single return points in the original point cloud
#these points were not used in the estimation of the trajectory
npoints(filter_single(las))
#> [1] 7699

#no of points in original point cloud
npoints(las)
#> [1] 108994 

#no of points in filtered point cloud with trajectory information
npoints(las2)
#> [1] 95583
```

Trajectory information is available for 88% (95583/108994) of the point cloud.

Follow up questions and strategies:

1. Is it possible to generate the trajectory information for single return pulses? I can think of interpolation based on neighbouring pulses
2. How to generate trajectory information for the erroneous returns?

Can the above questions be dealt with using `lidR` in order to have trajectory information for the entire point cloud as far as possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to generate the trajectory information for single return pulses? I can think of interpolation based on neighbouring pulses

*for* single return or *from* single returns? In the first case you misunderstood what `track_sensor()` does. It does not compute a trajectory for each pulse. It computes the trajectory of the sensor (embarked in an aircraft) at different discrete instants using multiple returns. In the later case, no, we can't draw a line using a single point and it does not matter because there is no need to use every single point. Several multiple returns are enough.

> How to generate trajectory information for the erroneous returns?

The trajectory information is available at different instant `t` and the coordinates are not linked to individual points. Computing the trajectory for erroneous points is consequently meaningless. You have 6 erroneous pulses that can't be used, this is not a big deal. It could have been a problem if 50 or 70% of the dataset would have been erroneous.

> Trajectory information is available for 88% (95583/108994) of the point cloud.

No. What is correct is that the sensor positions are computed *from* 88% of the points which is surprisingly high. It means that more than 90% of the pulses are multiple returns. So you definitively do not care of the 6 problematic points. In the example of the doc (that is somewhat extreme) it uses 212 pulses out of 56976 (0.4%) and it works well.

---

**Original anwser**

Sorry, your question is a bit messy and I do not understand exactly what is the problem. I will edit this answer later if you update your question to clarify. Right now I can only try to answer what I understand.

> Am I right in my understanding that I can't use the single returns any more?

To retrieve sensor position it looks at lines intersections in the sky (see the associated paper). To defines a line you need two points. Single returns are, by definition, not made of two points.

> Can I use other pulses with more than two first and last returns per pulse by filtering out intermediate returns?

`track_sensor()` already performs the point selection (selection of first last by pulse). You need to do nothing. The input is your point-cloud, let `track_sensor()` do the job. But if your dataset is badly populated `track_sensor()` will probably fail with a message.

> I understand that the duplicate return numbers could be due to rounded off gpstime. But in few instances that I looked at, it seems like the points are almost in a single line with return numbers 1,7,7,7, for example.

This is a problem and we are falling in the **badly populated** case. For a given gpstime, if you have 3 points labelled 7 your file is not valid. Something I have already seen is invalid files because the sensor returned more than 7 returns. LAS file format cannot store more than 7 in the return number attribute (3 bits field). So, for returns number above 7 the provided may have put 7. It might be your case and actually I'd say I'm 80% confident it is your case. If you perform more tests you should be able to detect if problematic pulses are always pulses with a 7.

> Can I use Z information to relabel the multiple returns with same return number? (The last return is probably the lowest point (ALS), no?)

If I'm correct you can remove the problematic points and keep one of the multiple 7th returns. No matter which one by the way. We need two aligned returns and a valid input. First and last are the best ones so I you can keep the lowest one it works.

Comment: I have formatted to question to highlight what I could do so far and what I need to do clearly.

Comment: Answer edited. I hope it helps